# How can I replace \ with / in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I tried with following regex, but it didn't work.

> myString.replaceAll("\", "/");

Exception:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Unexpected internal error near index 1
>   \  ^  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown
>   Source)

Comment: To convert to Unix separators for file path, you may want to have a look at apache common-io http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#separatorsToUnix%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Your code should not even compile.**

`"\"` escapes the `"` so that the string continues. Writing `String h = "\"hello\"";` makes the string `h` contain `"hello"`.

If we change then change it to it to `"\\"` (escaping the backslash) we run into another problem. The regular expression then tries to escape the *next* character. For example writing `"\\d+"` is a valid regular expression (matching digits).

---

In you case however you do not need regular expressions at all. Just use the `replace(char, char)` method of the string, it replaces **all** characters.

```
myString.replace('\\', '/');
```

---

By the way, if you are replacing paths, you should look at `File.separator` to get the systems *path separator character*.

Comment: This is the best answer by far (+1). Use regular expressions if and only if you need them. `String.replace(char, char)` and `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` should be the used in 80% of cases where people use String.replaceAll().

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need 4 slashes, because backslash is an escape character for regex as well.  Try

```
myString.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Comment: This is true, but it's solving the wrong problem (see dacwe's answer).